# How can I structure state in React when working with canvas API?

Tags: reactjs, canvas

I am working with canvas API where I have many rectangles that can be shown. These rectangles are connected to each other, and can be dragged (moved) on canvas. This canvas is basically a visual representation of data layer for the user.

In search of finding a best way to structure state which will hold information about all the rectangles, I structured state in `Recoil` state since that is the state library that we are using. Recoil state made it easy to sync data between multiple components, but I noticed that canvas was becoming extremely slow since every time I moved one rectangle, I had to update the whole state with `map` method and thus creating new objects in memory every time I move it by even an inch.

I've then tried this hack where data for canvas rectangles and connections between them was represented with `classes` where I created methods in a class to update objects, where they were directly mutated, I was just sending new array to react state, but objects were mutated. That sped up canvas interactions for a quite margin, but left a bad taste in my mouth that I wasn't really doing it the `react` way and that updating objects through methods on the object without making a shallow copy of it could lead to many potential problems. I couldn't achieve this with `Recoil` since it uses `Object.freeeze()` on every object in state array.

Problem that I am facing right now is having too many props passed around since I am keeping state for canvas in local `state`. I was trying to find the best way to structure state bearing in mind all the performance implications with `React` nature and many potential footguns.

My data looks kinda like this.

```
const stateArray = [
  firstTask: {
     rectangles: [],
     connections: [],
     id: 1,
     name: '',
     etc..
   },
   secondTask: {
     rectangles: [],
     connections: [],
     id: 1,
     name: '',
     etc..
   }
]
```

I have created a class for each object of the rectangle, where all the information about dimensions of them, and coordinates are stored.

For example, code for changing coordinates looks something like this:

```
setRectangles(prev => {
  return prev.map(rect => {
   if (rect.id === id) {
     rect.updateCoordinates(x, y)
   }
   return rect; 
})
}
```

As you can see, I am doing direct mutations on object through object methods. This was by far best approach performance wise for now, but it is honestly not looking very good from `React` immutability approach.

If anyone had any similar issue, or has any idea how can I structure this better, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have to update Recoil state for every pixel that your rectangle moves? Can you incrementally update state via debouncing or only update state once after the rectangle has been moved to its final position?

Answer (score 1):

### App state vs Ephemeral

Welcome to the border between app state and ephemeral state.

Ephemeral state is important to a component, but NOT semantically important to consumers of that component. For instance a dropdown *onChange* event is very important state to the app. But, its is open state, or is focused state is not.

So let's take the example of a rect that can be dragged around into 3 different zones, "Backlog", "InProgress" and "Done".

Each zone has semantic meaning to the rest of the app. e.g. I will want to update the count of rectangles in each zone.

When you start dragging the rectangle, the state splits. The original rectangle remains, but an ephemeral (temporary) twin is created - and is dragged. During this process, the app's state remains indifferent to the twin's position until it engages in a semantic action, such as dropping into a zone. Only then does the app state require an update.

Its important to note, the ephemeral state exists - it just doesn't need to be wired into your much slower app state logic.

### So what to do?

So you'd setup everything to drag n drop (or whatever) in ephemeral state (which is fast). And then update state, only when it's important.

e.g. the example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData) you would create state ONLY  on the drop

```html
<div>
  <p id="source" draggable="true">
    Select this element, drag it to the drop zone and then release the selection
    to move the element.
  </p>
</div>
<div id="target">Drop Zone</div>

<button id="reset">Reset example</button>
```

```js
const source = document.querySelector("#source");
source.addEventListener("dragstart", (ev) => {
  ev.currentTarget.classList.add("dragging");
  ev.dataTransfer.clearData();
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.target.id);
});
source.addEventListener("dragend", (ev) =>
  ev.target.classList.remove("dragging"),
);

const target = document.querySelector("#target");
target.addEventListener("dragover", (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
});
target.addEventListener("drop", (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  const data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  const source = document.getElementById(data);
  ev.target.appendChild(source);
  // UPDATE APP STATE HERE
  // setSelected(data);
  // ...
  // ...
});

const reset = document.querySelector("#reset");
reset.addEventListener("click", () => document.location.reload());
```

The same principle holds for canvas - let canvas handle its ephemeral state. But at key points, update app state.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no good libs to use react like approach (with components and hooks) with canvas directly.

But there is a really good react wrapper for [three.js](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/getting-started/introduction) library which use canvas under the hood. With this you will be able to encapsulate functionality into components with the help of utility hooks like `useFrame`. But keep in mind that although this library provides a lot of functionality and enables you to work with 3D models and even create games it is pretty heavy. You need to test it out if it works for your exact case.

Answer (score -2):

Structuring the state in React when working with the canvas API can be challenging due to the performance implications of frequently updating canvas elements. However, there are a few approaches you can take to balance performance and immutability.

1. Using Context API
   The Context API provides a way to share the state between components without having to pass props through the component tree. This can be useful for managing states related to the canvas, such as the list of rectangles and their coordinates.

```
const CanvasContext = React.createContext();

const CanvasProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [rectangles, setRectangles] = React.useState([]);

  const handleUpdateRectangle = (id, x, y) => {
    const updatedRectangles = rectangles.map(rectangle => {
      if (rectangle.id === id) {
        return { ...rectangle, x, y };
      }
      return rectangle;
    });
    setRectangles(updatedRectangles);
  };

  return (
    <CanvasContext.Provider value={{ rectangles, handleUpdateRectangle }}>
      {children}
    </CanvasContext.Provider>
  );
};

const Canvas = () => {
  const { rectangles, handleUpdateRectangle } = React.useContext(CanvasContext);

  // Use rectangles and handleUpdateRectangle to render and interact with the canvas
};
```

2. Using a State Management Library
   State management libraries like Redux or MobX can help manage complex state and provide tools for immutability and performance optimization. These libraries can be particularly useful when dealing with large amounts of data or when a state needs to be shared across multiple components.

```
    const store = createStore(reducer);
    
    const Canvas = () => {
      const rectangles = useSelector(state => state.rectangles);
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      const handleUpdateRectangle = (id, x, y) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_RECTANGLE', id, x, y });
      };
    
      // Use rectangles and handleUpdateRectangle to render and interact with the canvas
    };
```

3. Optimizing State Updates
   Regardless of the state management approach you choose, it's important to optimize state updates to avoid unnecessary re-renders. This can be done by using shallow copies of objects or using a memoization technique like useMemo to prevent recalculation of expensive functions.

```
    const updateRectangle = React.useCallback((id, x, y) => {
      const updatedRectangle = { ...rectangle, x, y };
      setRectangles(prevRectangles => prevRectangles.map(rectangle => {
        if (rectangle.id === id) {
          return updatedRectangle;
        }
        return rectangle;
      }));
    }, [rectangle]);
```

4. Using Custom Hooks
   Custom hooks can provide a reusable way to manage state and handle interactions related to the canvas. This can help encapsulate the logic and keep components focused on their specific responsibilities.

```
    const useCanvasState = () => {
      const [rectangles, setRectangles] = React.useState([]);
    
      const handleUpdateRectangle = (id, x, y) => {
        const updatedRectangles = rectangles.map(rectangle => {
          if (rectangle.id === id) {
            return { ...rectangle, x, y };
          }
          return rectangle;
        });
        setRectangles(updatedRectangles);
      };
    
      return { rectangles, handleUpdateRectangle };
    };

    const Canvas = () => {
      const { rectangles, handleUpdateRectangle } = useCanvasState();
    
      // Use rectangles and handleUpdateRectangle to render and interact with the canvas
    };
```

By considering these approaches and optimizing state updates, you can effectively manage the state in React while working with the canvas API, ensuring both performance and maintainability.

Comment: This is chatgpt